# Why don't my turtles swim back to their home beach?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I breed two turtles they either freeze and don’t dig in the sand (which I have) or they hop back into the ocean and don’t go onto land to lay eggs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm just checking, what are you feeding them?

Comment: Note it can't be any sand - it must be a Beach biome.

Comment: You're really hard to understand, can you please use punctuation marks?

Answer (score 1):

When breeding, the turtle tries to return to its [home beach](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Turtle#Home_beach) to lay the eggs.

The special case you are describing (being still) can happen if the home beach is not available anymore or the turtle failed to find a path to it.

If they are hopping into the water, they might try to return to their home beach.

Check the following:

- Is it possible that the home beach was destroyed, e.g. by you removing the blocks?
- Did the breeding actually take place? The turtle carrying the eggs appears bigger than the other.
- If after breeding they hop into the ocean, follow them in a boat - they might be returning to their home beach.